# React i18next - Get language preference from API and initialize i18n based on fetched preference

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-i18next

I am using React i18next library to do language translations in my react app.

I need to fetch the language preference from API (Say User settings api) and then i need to initialize i18n with the language i got from API.

But my i18n.js file initializes first (obviously) before API call being served. Not sure how to handle this. I am using react hooks and all functional components.

Please find below my code and my index.js has the below file imported

```
// i18n.js
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import translationEN from "./locale/en/translation.json";
import translationES from "./locale/es/translation.json";

const resources = {
    es: {
        translation: translationES,
    },
    en: {
        translation: translationEN,
    },
};

i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
    resources,
    fallbackLng: "es",

    keySeparator: false,

    interpolation: {
        escapeValue: false,
    },
});

export default i18n;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not get the language from <html lang="fr">. Set the language as a global var on server page render, index.js can read it.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the user's language setting you can update the language through

```
i18n.changeLanguage(lang)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch API from the server when init app and then use API `addResourceBundle` of i18n to add locale file to i18init

Ref: https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#addresourcebundle

Answer (score 0):

In order to make api call "inside" i18n I suggest using 3rdParty module.
You may do it like that:

Create 3rdParty module to fetch from API:

```
import { HttpApiClient } from './api-client'
import { i18n, ThirdPartyModule } from 'i18next'

async function fetchLanguageList(): Promise<string[]> {
  try {
    const { data } = await HttpApiClient.getLanguageList
    return data.map(language => language.code || '')
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    return []
  }
}

export const languageCodesFromRemote: ThirdPartyModule = {
  type: '3rdParty',
  init: async (i18next: i18n) => {
    const fallbackLng = i18next.options.fallbackLng
    const languagesList = await fetchLanguageList()
    i18next.options.fallbackLng =
      languagesList.length > 0 ? languagesList : fallbackLng
  },
}
```

Then you may use it like below

```
import { getLanguagePreferancesFromAPI } from 
'./modules/languageCodesModule'

const init = (options: I18nOptions = {}) =>
  i18next
    .use(ChainedBackend)
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .use(getLanguagePreferancesFromAPI) // here you can use your 
imported module
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init(
      ...
```